# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

- What went wrong:
  **Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.**
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 46s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path xxx
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native run-android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-23T11_07_55_756Z-debug.log

I tried all solutions from these questions but no help, please help me to resolve this issue:
[Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390956/task-installdebug-not-found-in-project-app)
[I get error on my react-native app while I am trying to execute following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936948/i-get-error-on-my-react-native-app-while-i-am-trying-to-execute-following-code)
[React-native and it dont work, accusing some error "Task 'installRelease' not found in project ':app'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433095/react-native-and-it-dont-work-accusing-some-error-task-installrelease-not-fo)

I tried  :
react-native start --reset-cache 
npm start --reset-cache
npm install
gradlew clean
Invalid cache restart

Comment: can you tell what you tried to do that made the error show up ? and also add the full error please

Comment: check the above lines or below lines of this there is usually an exception from a library or something in your dev env

Comment: I have updated complete log of error and also the solution I tried, please check